# Matlab - different color to each plot

Tags: matlab

Assume I create `figure(1)` and draw on it multiple graph with `plot` , like that -

```
figure(1)
plot(...) 
.
.
.
plot(...) // all the plot's with different color
```

Is there any option set `figure(1)` such that it will draw each `plot`with different color ?

Comment: Easiest way is by using `hold all`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
plot(f,R,'m--','LineWidth',2);
```

There are plenty of options, if you execute `help plot` you'll get the whole available set.